# Which HTTP verb to use to trigger publication of Kafka messages

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

**Background** 
I need to implement a way for developers in our team and the product owner to be able to trigger the re publication of some Kafka messages after querying the DB for our Spring Boot application. DB will be queried for the data but no modification will be performed. So the action has no effect on the resource held by the application.

**Potential Solution**
I am thinking about implementing a REST endpoint to achieve this. I know that this is not a good use case to be implemented via REST as there is no "State Tranfer" for the resources held by the application. So...

**Question**

1. Any other recommendations for alternative ways to achieve this apart from REST endpoint ?
2. If I were implement it via a REST endpoint which HTTP verb should I use ?

( I have checked and haven't found any answered question of this nature in any previous SO post. )

Comment: Why not simply using a Servlet with a GET or POST request (use the verb you like)?

Comment: Http POST method

Comment: "So the action has no effect on the resource held by the application. " Maybe you should define this method on a different resource then. The action does have an effect somewhere else after all. Something like `POST /the/database/resource/kafkaMessage` on top of your existing `/the/database/resource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which HTTP verb to use to trigger publication of Kafka messages?

You answer this question by reviewing the semantics of the HTTP methods, and deciding which is appropriate to your use case.

For this example, the reasonable candidates are `GET` and `POST`.  (Technically, you could consider `HEAD`, which is sort of a specialized case of `GET` -- I'll ignore it here).

The important distinction to understand is that GET semantics include [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1); the description is "effectively read only", but the important bits are the implications of that.

> The purpose of distinguishing between safe and unsafe methods is to allow automated retrieval processes (spiders) and cache performance optimization (pre-fetching) to work without fear of causing harm.

Automated retrieval means that you may see `GET` requests even when there is no business motivation for them.  If that's OK, then using GET is fine -- and it even has some advantages when the requests are being sent across an unreliable network.

On the other hand, if republishing is "expensive" or should otherwise only be done "on purpose", then `POST` is a more appropriate choice.

It might help to imagine this in the context of a web page in a browser.  If you provide access via an [a element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element), then the browser is allowed to try to optimize the user experience by pre-fetching the resource.  On the other hand, using a [form element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-form-element) with
`method: POST` won't be pre-fetched, because compliant browsers are aware that the request isn't expected to be safe.

> Online opinion about [REST] seems to be divided.

REST suffers a lot from what Martin Fowler called [Semantic Diffusion](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SemanticDiffusion.html).

> Semantic diffusion occurs when you have a word that is coined a person or group, often with a pretty good definition, but then gets spread through the wider community in a way that weakens that definition. This weakening risks losing the definition entirely - and with it any usefulness to the term.

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is an [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5); the reference application built using that style is the [World Wide Web](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm).

> The only other open question which remains is, whether REST is the right way to trigger a job

Depends on the constraints you are operating under, and how ambitious you are being.  "Everybody" has web clients available to them, so it's a cheap way to transport a message from client to server.  On the other hand, HTTP requests are not micro small, and there's lots of capability built in that may be no more than drag in your use case.

Horses for courses.

Comment: In my specific use case, the act of publishing of Kafka messages is a bit of an expensive operation in the backend, and will only be triggered on express purpose. Also in the future, we might provide a way for this to be triggered via a button on a UI page. Given these reasons, and your analogy with the web browser made me realise that POST is indeed the best verb to use in this case. The only other open question which remains is, whether REST is the right way to trigger a job ?  I am leaning towards REST coz it is super easy to implement it. Online opinion about it seems to be divided.